# What does the path parameter is in unix_connect for websockets python?

Tags: python, linux, sockets, unix, websocket

I'm not posting any code since I'm trying to understand the method from the documentation https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/8.1/api.html#websockets.client.unix_connect.

Precisely, I'm referring to this method:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GqfA.png

My question is: what is path? Below is written "file system path to the Unix socket" but I'm not understanding to which file or folder is referring.

Comment: Are you trying to use a unix socket?

Comment: A unix domain socket is (usually) represented by an entry in the filesystem created when a server binds a socket to that path.

Comment: @Shawn where can I find this entry in the filesystem? Is this fix or every time it changes?

Comment: It's whatever the server program uses as the path.

Comment: @VipulLearning If your program is a server, your program creates it. If your program is a client, then you have to use the same path where the server created it. I think your real question is "What are Unix sockets?"

Comment: @user253751 Yes you're right, this is my question. Unix has particular stuff for sockets?

Comment: Does this off-site resource answer your question? [What are UNIX sockets and how do they work?](https://www.howtogeek.com/devops/what-are-unix-sockets-and-how-do-they-work/)